# How to have a Score Integer updated and displayed in Cocos2d?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am obviously making a game that has a score. How do I call an update method and have the integer actually displayed in the Top-Right corner?

Comment: Do you want it to update every second or something similar?

Comment: @allthewayapps i would like it to update every time the user kills an enemy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here, this might work

**In the .h file:**

```
@interface HelloWorld : CCLayer {
    int score;    
    CCLabelTTF *scoreLabel;
}

- (void)addPoint;
```

**In the .m file:**

> **In the init method:**

```
//Set the score to zero.
score = 0;

//Create and add the score label as a child.
scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"8" fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:24];
scoreLabel.position = ccp(240, 160); //Middle of the screen...
[self addChild:scoreLabel z:1];
```

**Somewhere else:**

```
- (void)addPoint
{
    score = score + 1; //I think: score++; will also work.
    [scoreLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", score]];
}
```

***Now just call: [self addPoint]; whenever the user kills an enemy.***

*That should work, tell me if it didn't because I have not tested it.*

Comment: thanks again, ive noticed you appearing in a few of my questions! and thanks for your help. now check out my most recent question about an AI. I could REALLY use some help there.

Comment: @ipodfreak0313: Haha. Glad that I could help! =)  I took a look at your AI question, but unfortunately I have never tried to make my own AI before.  I might have some ideas though.  I'll think about it and let you know if I come up with anything.

Comment: thanks man, i wish i could answer some questions for you, but i am still very new to cocos2d (okay, maybe not new, but i have a lot to learn).

Answer (score 3):

in header file:

```
@interface GameLayer : CCLayer
{
    CCLabelTTF *_scoreLabel;
}

-(void) updateScore:(int) newScore;
```

in implementation file:

```
-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
      // ..

      // add score label
      _scoreLabel = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:@"0" dimensions:CGSizeMake(200,30) alignment:UITextAlignmentRight fontName:@"Marker Felt" fontSize:30]; 
      [self addChild:_scoreLabel];
      _scoreLabel.position = ccp( screenSize.width-100, screenSize.height-20);

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) updateScore:(int) newScore {
    [_scoreLabel setString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newScore]];
}
```

**EDIT**: if you don't want to use an ivar, you can use tags:

```
[self addChild:scoreLabel z:0 tag:kScoreLabel];
// ...
CCLabelTTF *scoreLabel = (CCLabelTTF*)[self getChildByTag:kScoreLabel];
```

**EDIT 2**: For performance reasons you should switch to `CCLabelAtlas` or `CCBitmapFontAtlas` if you update the score very frequently.

Also read the [cocos2d programming guide about labels](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3alabels).

Comment: do I have to schedule an update that calls the function updateScore:(int)newScore ?

Answer (score 0):

Using UILabel

```
UILabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",score];
```

Move the UILabel in the top of the view using interface builder
you could also create it programmatically

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,500,30)];
[[self view] addSubview:label];
[label release]; // dont leak :)
```

Comment: @ipodfreak0313: No need for CAPS, UILabel works fine for Cocos2D too, I mean, you render the content into a UIView too and can add other stuff into the view hierarchy. Plus: UIKits text rendering is far better than Cocos2Ds.

Comment: @JustSid: I'm pretty sure that it is recommended not to render UIKit elements on top of a cocos2d scene, but I may be wrong.

Comment: @allthewayapps: There are some general tips/guidelines on how to handle UIViews on top of an EAGLLayer view, but Apple made its very own techdemo on how to render fast and how to render UI in a 3D OpenGL ES game and they also used UIKit (see the WWDC 2010 videos for more info).